# How to convert a string tensor to a PIL Image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I have a string Tensor object that I produced by calling `tf.io.encode_jpeg` on an image Tensor [(Documentation for encode_jpeg)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/encode_jpeg).

How do I convert this string Tensor into a PIL Image?

I've tried calling `Image.fromarray(encoded_tensor.numpy())`, but this returns `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'`.

Comment: Can you post the full code used for conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an in-memory (rather than on-disk) JPEG-encoded image. You can check if that is correct by printing the start of the buffer:

```
print(encoded_tensor[:10])
```

and seeing if it starts with the JPEG magic number `ff d8 ff`.

If so, you need to wrap it in a `BytesIO` and open it into a `PIL Image` with:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(BytesIO(encoded_tensor))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error here is caused because you are not decoding the image. To decode the image, use `tf.io.decode_jpeg`. Please find the working code below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image

img=tf.keras.utils.load_img('/content/dog.1.jpg')
img=tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)

#encode_jpeg encodes a tensor of type uint8 to string
encode_img=tf.io.encode_jpeg(img,'rgb')

#decode_jpeg decodes the string tensor to a tensor of type uint8
decode_img=tf.io.decode_jpeg(encode_img)

Image.fromarray(decode_img.numpy())
```