PIL: How can I open (read Metadata) a file if its path uses Windows Shell Namespace?
I'm trying to open a file from a device (iPhone) to get its EXIF.
The path to file looks as:
"::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\::{55DE1ED1-3F3E-4C88-BC1A-819EFF0BE330}\73cdac9ad5200bebf6ab95998c1bed571f70fd23\PhotoLibrary\photo_library.album.all_assets\A2FD049A03544E90B70243069CB28014.JPG"
But I get an exception:
AssertionError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
There are no problems with the file located on the local disk, it has a normal path D:\image.jpg
I also can open file in Windows Explorer by this path:
::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\::{55DE1ED1-3F3E-4C88-BC1A-819EFF0BE330}\73cdac9ad5200bebf6ab95998c1bed571f70fd23\PhotoLibrary\photo_library.album.all_assets\A2FD049A03544E90B70243069CB28014.JPG
I think exception happens in this file:
\venv\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py
in function:
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
Are there any ways to open a file with Windows Shell Namespace?

Open the file and get its contents using standard read() or contents = Path('Windows mess').read_bytes(). Then wrap the result in a io.BytesIO and pass the result to Pillow's Image.open(). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72642433/2836621

Thank you Mark Setchell for the your advise, but I can't access to my file  with Windows Shell Namespace inside path using open() and read() functions.
I've found the solution here

So I found a way to read EXIF ​​data from an image I have on an iPhone without using Pillow. I modified the code from this answer to:
file = Path("::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\::{55DE1ED1-3F3E-4C88-BC1A-819EFF0BE330}\\73cdac9ad5200bebf6ab95998c1bed571f70fd23\\PhotoLibrary\\photo_library.album.all_assets\\CD45D43B46DB40E7B1B66F33D7504040.HEIC")
sh = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application',0)
ns = sh.NameSpace(str(file.parent))
file_name = ns.ParseName(file.name)

colnum = 0
columns = []

while True:
    colname=ns.GetDetailsOf(None, colnum)
    if not colname:
        break
    columns.append(colname)
    colnum += 1

for colnum in range(len(columns)):
    colval=ns.GetDetailsOf(file_name, colnum)
    if colval:
        print('\t', columns[colnum], colval)


Output:

 Name IMG_0037.HEIC
 Date 2024/06/26:06:38:18.000
 Type HEIC File
 Size 1535829
 Rating 16
 Date taken 2024/06/26:06:38:18.000
 Date modified 2024/06/26:06:38:18.000
 Date created 2024/06/26:06:38:18.000
 Latitude x
 Longitude x
 Altitude x
 Width 3024
 Height 4032

